# Max and min of $f(x,y)=-e^{x^4+y^2}+x^2+y^2+1$

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f$ is $C^\infty(R^2)$ and if I consider $f(x,y)=-e^{x^4+y^2}+x^2+y^2+1$ for $x\rightarrow+\infty$ and $y=0$ the function is not limited down. 
The function is symmetric respect to the axis and the origin.
Are there other points that make null gradient except the origin?

I have calculated Hessian matrix and found the origin is a local minimun. But up?

Comment: Are you sure it's $e^{x^4+y^2}$ and not $e^{-(x^4+y^2)}$? If it isn't then $f$ has no minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is a saddle point for $f(x,y)=-e^{y^2+x^4}+x^2+y^2+1$. The graph of $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a paraboloid of revolution, while the graph of $h(x,y)=e^{y^2+x^4}-1$ is gaussian-shaped, so there have to be points of absolute maximum in the region $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.

$\hspace{1in}$[image]

By studying the gradient of $f$ we have that such points of absolute maximum occur over the line $y=0$, hence the problem boils down to finding the absolute maximum of $1+x^2-e^{x^4}$ or $1+z-e^{z^2}$ over the interval $(0,1)$. This problem can be solved through Lambert's $W$ function. The absolute maximum of $1+z-e^{z^2}$ occurs at $z=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\,W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$, hence the absolute maximum of $f$ is $\approx 0.22708552122$.